# errorHandling in Vue 3 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on migrating my Vue project to version 3.0.

I'm encountering an odd error when wanting to use the `errorHandler` function. Here is how I'm instantiating it in `main.ts`.

```js
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.errorHandler = (err: unknown, instance: ComponentPublicInstance | null, info: string) => {
  // handling the error
}

[...]
```

I've also added a definition inside a declaration file.

```js
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $errorHandler: (err: unknown, instance: ComponentPublicInstance | null, info: string) => void;
  }
}
```

Every time, the function is being called I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.$errorHandler is not a function
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm doing the same thing for other global variables instantiated on `app.config.globalProperties` and it works properly.

Anybody has encountered the same issue?

**UPDATE**

Is it a good practice to assign the `errorHandler` to a global property?

```js
app.config.globalProperties.errorHandler = app.config.errorHandler;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to explicitly call the `errorHandler`, but you can't do that. Also, the error handler is not exposed as `$errorHandler`. Not sure where you got that. The `errorHandler` prop is not a Vue global property, so you don't need to add typings for it.

Comment: How should I use it? Can't I call it in `catch` for example?